# Why WinForms ComboBox Selected Text Propriety is empty?

Tags: mysql, winforms, combobox

I am using Winform and MySQL in my project.

When I try to get the ComboBox Vales in Different Method I saw the ComboBox Selected Text Propriety is empty.

Why it is empty?.

And Please say the Difference b/w ComboBox Selected Item and Selected text?.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`SelectedItem` is the combobox item which is selected by the user, whereas the `SelectedText` property contains the possible selected part of the item text.

In your example "CITY" is the string representation of the selected item. If the user only selects "IT" in the text area of the combobox (if possible) this is the value of `SelectedText`.